# Pass ARG from docker-compose.yml to a docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

So I have a NodeJS API which I have created, which contains a Private NPM package in the package.json.

I have the following Docker files in this project:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ARG NPM_TOKEN
COPY .npmrc ./  
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install  
RUN rm -f ./.npmrc
COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**.npmrc**

`//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}`

I have managed to build this API by running the command:

`docker build --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=${MY_NPM_TOKEN} -t api:1.0.0 .`

This successfully builds the image.

In my main application, I have a docker-compose.yml which I want to run this image.

`version: '3' services: redis: container_name: redis image: redis:3.2.8 ports: - "6379:6379" volumes: - ./data:/data api: container_name: api image: api:1.0.0 build: context: . args: - NPM_TOKEN={MY_NPM_TOKEN} ports: - "3001:3001"`

When I run `docker-compose up` it fails with the error:

`Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_TOKEN}`

Does anyone have an idea, why my image is not taking in the `ARG` that is passed?

Comment: I think you should be using `docker-compose build` for testing but either way if the image doesn't exist it will build. How are you setting `$MY_NPM_TOKEN`? Do you have an .env file?

Comment: @leeman24 `${MY_NPM_TOKEN}` is a string which is a token from NPM so an example of what it looks like in my compose is: `- NPM_TOKEN=4884nfhf939fn39`

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you are trying to pass the `NPM_TOKEN` arguments from the environment variable named `MY_NPM_TOKEN`.

However, there is an error in the syntax that you should update your `docker-compose.yaml` file

from `- NPM_TOKEN={MY_NPM_TOKEN}`

to `- NPM_TOKEN=${MY_NPM_TOKEN}`